# Ошибка входа пользователя

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Создаю проект в Visual Studio 2010
ASP.NET MVC 2 Empty Web Application.
Добавляю папку App_Data.
Добавляю в нее New Item... файл Database1.mdf типа SQL Server Database.
Появляется сообщение "Ошибка входа пользователя" и БД не создается и не добавляется в проект.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте запустить VS от имени (с правами) администратор